# Bluetooth proximity in OSX

Tags: macos, bluetooth, signal-strength

Is there a way or an application in OSX that can tell me if a Bluetooth device is near the computer? Maybe via signal strength? I know there are things out there to check for the existence of a Bluetooth connection but thats not what i'm looking for.

I'm using http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/ and it works mostly but my phone makes a Bluetooth connection even if I'm not close to my computer. I'd like to know if I'm next to (1 foot or closer) to my laptop, not 20-30 feet as it stands now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most useful for you would be [Proximity](http://code.google.com/p/reduxcomputing-proximity/); it can run any AppleScript when you're within a certain distance of your computer.

-OR-

You can take a look at [BlueProximity](http://blueproximity.sourceforge.net/) (should be compile-able for OS X if there are no binaries available). Instead of getting it to lock your screen/log you off, you could set it to, for example, show a Growl alert when you are within a certain distance of your computer.